# Why does fail() fired when there's no error in $.when()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred, .when

I"m using JQuery v2.0.0

I'm trying to understand the deferred objects and I got an unexpected result.  The fail() was fired even though there's no visible or known error here.

```
function foo1() { alert('testing'); }

$.when(foo1())
  .done(alert('success'))
  .fail(alert('fail'))
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must pass your callbacks as *functions*:

```
$.when(foo1())
    .done(function() {
        alert('success');
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('fail');
    });
```

Currently, you're attempting to register the `undefined` result of *immediately* calling `alert('fail')` as your `.fail` handler.

Although you didn't say so, you will be seeing both the `success` *and* `fail` alerts appearing, which should provide a hint that you did something wrong ;-)

Comment: Yea, I can tell I did something wrong.  :-)  One quick question, is it valid or allowed if I do this without a "foo" function wrapper --> $.when( alert('test') ).done(function(){}).fail(function(){});

Comment: Still waiting for 5 minutes to be up so I can click answer to your question.

Comment: @fletchsod in this particular case, putting the `alert` call directly in `$.when` will result in the `done` callback being invoked - it's only the return result from the expression inside `.when` that matters.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing a function reference to the `done` and `fail` functions you are invoking them

```
function foo1() {
    alert('testing');
}

$.when(foo1())
    .done(function () {
    alert('success')
})
    .fail(function () {
    alert('fail')
})
```